# How to find center of google map polyline having more than two cordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, center, polyline

I am working on asp.net mvc 3 project we are using Google maps.I want to display marker at center of poly line.
I am using below code

```
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(
    MyMapCordinates[0].lat(),
    MyMapCordinates[0].lng()
);
var End = new google.maps.LatLng(
    MyMapCordinates[MyMapCordinates.length - 1].lat(),
    MyMapCordinates[MyMapCordinates.length - 1].lng()
);
debugger
var inBetween = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start, End, 0.5);
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
    position: inBetween
});
```

It is working fine with polyline having two coordinates. But it fails for polyline with more than three co-ordinates. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The interpolate method is designed only to work with two sets of coordinates. The computeLength() method looks like what you are looking for to calculate the distance of multiple points, and then just do some math to find the middle.

Does that help?

Comment: Hi user2110100 Thanks. I have calculated length of polyline using  computeLength() and diveded it by 2 to get the half of polyline.further i am  using  computeOffset method to find the center Lat lngs to put marker at that location.But still this is not working with polyline with more than two co ordinates..

Comment: the total length of the polyline, the difference between start and finish, what looks like the center to the eye, a weighted two dimensional shape?